# How to colour the edges after using sobel filter?

Tags: matlab, edge-detection, sobel

I am using sobel filter for edge detection. How to illustrate the gradient direction with color coding. For example, horizontal edges with blue and vertical edges with yellow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can specify whether you want horizontal or vertical edge detected (check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html#inputarg_direction)), you could perform 2 filtering operations (one horizontal and the other vertical) and save each resulting image, then concatenating them to form a final, 3-channels RGB image.

The RGB color code for yellow is `[1 1 0]` and that of blue is `[0 0 1]`, so in your case the vertical edge image will occupy the first 2 channels whereas the horizontal edge image will occupy the last channel.

Example:

```
clear
clc
close all

A = imread('circuit.tif');

[r,c,~] = size(A);

EdgeH = edge(A,'Sobel','Horizontal');
EdgeV = edge(A,'Sobel','Vertical');

%// Arrange the binary images to form a RGB color image.
FinalIm = zeros(r,c,3,'uint8');

FinalIm(:,:,1) = 255*EdgeV;
FinalIm(:,:,2) = 255*EdgeV;
FinalIm(:,:,3) = 255*EdgeH;

figure;

subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(A)

subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(FinalIm)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you so much.That worked perfectly.But if say I have extracted diagonal edge also and plot with another color.What should I do?

Comment: Great glad to help! To display another set of edges with a different color, you will need to play with the Red, Green and Blue channels of `FinalIm`. Please have a look at my answer at the end of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550252/change-color-of-a-specific-region-in-eye-image-matlab/27554155#27554155) post, in which the user selects a color to fill a region with. The same methodology would apply for you; in your current case the `mask` would be every the vertical, horizontal and diagonal edge images.