# highlight (color) the abnormalities in the image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to circle or highlight (color-fill) the abnormalities on breast cancer image. Is there anyway that a Matlab can detect the abnormalities automatically and distinguish between normal and abnormal image. If not, then please guide me how to show this difference manually.

Thank you for your time in advance.

[Breast cancer image is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Gvq.gif)

Comment: How do you define such abnormalities? Doing such a task automatically requires quite some work; have you tried anything at all?

Comment: If you know which the abnormalities are you can use a region growing algorithm. If you want to get an automatic segmentation you might have to use a machine learning approach and invest some work.

Comment: I am a beginner and new to Matlab. I am working on term paper on use of image processing and breast cancer. I already used intensity value, histeq, ROI however never worked or used anything that helps me circle the abnormalities other than ifindcircles. Therefore, I don't have any code handy. I am so sorry.

Comment: Can you describe what the abnormalities are in your images ? You have to realize that most of us are not specialists of your domain, so we don't know how to read such medical image. I'd be happy to help if I knew what to search for ...

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550252/change-color-of-a-specific-region-in-eye-image-matlab/27554155#27554155) question and both answers; they should help get you started.

Comment: You can also try this method for manual region growing algorithm http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32532-region-growing--2d-3d-grayscale-

Comment: Where is the abnormality?

Comment: There are PhD thesis on this.

Comment: I am so sorry for late reply, I had an Dr appointment. @Ratbert and Parag - the small white dot on the image is tumor. I need a code for either highlighting/color coding the tumor automatically or circle it. -Thanks for your time.

Comment: There are many white dots ... can you post another image on which you circled the tumor ?

Comment: Thank you all for your time I asked my professor and he told me to just use imellipse function. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using imellipse function. Thanks for all your help.